# Anyone doing anything yet with Adobe's Project Alchemy?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash, alchemy

Making another appearance this year at MAX was [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/), Adobe's C/C++-to-AVM2-bytecode compiler.  It seems like really interesting stuff -- I haven't yet had time to really dig in and try it out myself, but I can definitely imagine putting it to good use.  Wondering whether any of you've had a chance to have a look at it yet, and if so, what kinds of things you've tried, how they've gone, what your opinions are, and the like.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have played a bit with Alchemy; tried to port swfmill to AS3.

My project stalled because I would really need a good compression library...after all I cannot drag a library along with my C code ;)

Also, I found out that it is, at this stage, more reliable to read your files from Flex then pass their content to the C code than trying to read them in your C code itself.

I have an example of how I do this on my blog.